# go build doesn't recognise methods

Tags: go, microservices

I try to setup a small Golang Microservice for users with Gin and Mongodb.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/wzslr321/artiver/entity"
    "github.com/wzslr321/artiver/settings"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

type application struct {
    users *entity.UserCollection
}

var app *application

func init() {
    initMongo()
}

func initMongo() {

    oc := options.Client().ApplyURI(settings.MongodbSettings.Uri)

    client, err := mongo.NewClient(oc)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error occured while initializing a new mongo client: %v", err)
    }

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 15*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    err = client.Connect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Errorr occurred while connecting to a client: %v", err)
    }

    defer func() {
        if err = client.Disconnect(ctx); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    log.Println("Successfully connected to the database!")


    app = &application{
        users: &entity.UserCollection{
            C: client.Database("artiver").Collection("users"),
        },
    }
}


func main() {

    router := app.InitRouter()
```

It doesn't show any errors in my IDE ( GoLand ), but when I try to build it I get an error:

```
# command-line-arguments
users/cmd/app/main.go:67:15: app.InitRouter undefined (type *application has no field or method InitRouter)
```

[image: Init router method autocompletion]

It it easily visible on the image above, that I do have access to such a method. It is defined in the same package.

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    cors "github.com/rs/cors/wrapper/gin"
    "net/http"
)


func (app *application) InitRouter() *gin.Engine {
    r := gin.New()

    r.Use(gin.Recovery())
    r.Use(cors.Default())

    r.GET("/", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        ctx.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello World")
    })

    user := r.Group("/api/user")
    {
        user.POST("/add", app.CreateUser)

    }

    return r
}
```

I have no idea how am I supposed to fix it and what is done wrong. I'd appreciate any hint about what isn't done correctly.

Comment: Share the project structure, please? I just want to confirm if both the files belong to the same package (i.e., package main in same directory)

Comment: *"but when I try to build it I get an error"* -- *How* are you building it? This is a an error often caused by mistakenly using `go run main.go` to build and run the program, doing that you're explicitly telling the compiler to compile *only* the `main.go` file. If you are building through the IDE then check the IDE's settings and make sure that it itself isn't using that unfortunate command to build the program.

Comment: @xdsarkar

This is my whole project file structure:
```
├── Dockerfile
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── bin
│   ├── build-errors.log
│   └── cmd
├── conf
│   ├── conf_dev.ini
│   └── path.go
├── entity
│   ├── error.go
│   ├── user.go
│   └── user_test.go
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── settings
│   └── settings.go
└── users
    ├── cmd
    │   └── app
    │       ├── main.go
    │       ├── main_test.go
    │       ├── router.go
    │       └── user.go
    └── presenter
        └── user.go
```

Comment: Yes @mkopriva I try to build it using: `go build users/cmd/app/main.go`

Comment: @Wiktor then that's your problem.

Comment: @Wiktor see: https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program, specifically this: *"Typically the package is specified as a list of .go source files from a single directory, but it may also be an `import path`, `file system path`, or `pattern matching a single known package`, as in `go run .` or `go run my/cmd`. "*

Comment: Oh yeah, I think I see the mistake now. I will  try to fix it now and share solution as answer. Thank you.

Comment: mkopriva, Wiktor: would one of you please post your comment as an actual answer to this question? It shows up on SO as “unanswered” despite the underlying problem and solution being well-understood.

Comment: @bcmills , I just posted an answer, sorry for being late with it, I've forgotten about it.

Answer (score 0):

Answer based on @mkopriva help in comments.

The issue was related to not running all needed .go files.
In my case, the solution was to build it this way in my Makefile:
`go build -o $(path)users cmd/app/*`

In similar cases, `go run .` most likely will do the job.